# JUnit with Spring Boot in n-tier Service Layer

Tags: java, junit, mockito, spring-restcontroller

I have a model

```
public class Student {

    private String name;

    // getter and setter
}
```

I have implemented a REST controller which generates a student object with random chars as name in it. I have a @RestController, bind with a @Service layer which serves student object and again a @Service layer which generates random strings. I want to test my application using JUnit by mocking my controller and services. The problem is I can mock my controller and service that serves student but stringGeneratorService service layer is not mocked.

My Controller

```
@RestController
public class StudentServer {

    StudentService service;

    @Autowired
    public StudentServer(StudentService service) {
        this.service = service;
    }

    @GetMapping("/generate-student")
    public Student studentGenerator() {
        return service.getRandomStudent();
    }
}
```

My Service layer that serves student object

```
@Service("studentService")
public class StudentService {

    StringGeneratorService stringService;

    @Autowired
    public StudentService(StringGeneratorService stringService) {
        this.stringService = stringService;
    }

    public Student getRandomStudent() {
        Student student = new Student();
        student.setName(stringService.generateRandomAlphaString());
        return student;
    }   

}
```

And my RandomStringGenertor Service

```
@Service("stringGeneratorService")
public class StringGeneratorService {

    Random random = new Random();

    public String generateRandomAlphaNumericString() {
        // returns a randomly generated string
    }
}
```

My JUnit test class as follows:

```
@RunWith(SpringRunner.class)
@WebMvcTest(StudentServer.class)
public class RestTest {

    @Autowired
    private MockMvc mockMvc;

    @TestConfiguration
    public static class TestConfig {
      @Bean
      public StudentService studentService(final StringGeneratorService stringGeneratorService){
       return new StudentService(stringGeneratorService);
      }
      @Bean
      public StringGeneratorService stringGeneratorService(){
        return mock(StringGeneratorService.class);
      }
    }

    @Autowired
    private StudentService studentService;

    @Autowired
    public StringGeneratorService stringGeneratorService;

    @Before
    public void setUp() {
      reset(stringGeneratorService);
    }

    @After
    public void tearDown() {
      verifyNoMoreInteractions(stringGeneratorService);
    }

    @Test
    public void testGenerateStudent() throws Exception {

         mockMvc.perform(MockMvcRequestBuilders.get("/generate-student"))
          .andExpect(MockMvcResultMatchers.status().isOk())
          .andDo(print())
          .andExpect(MockMvcResultMatchers.jsonPath("$.name").isNotEmpty());

    }
}
```

The result is Body = {"name":null}

Can anybody have any idea what am I doing wrong?

Answer (score 0):

In your test configuration to define a mock for your `StringGeneratorService`: `return mock(StringGeneratorService.class);`, but you don't define a mocked behavior of a method. The default behavior of many method returning an Object is to return `null`, which you see in your result.

You need to define a mocked behavior of the method like this:

```
@Bean
public StringGeneratorService stringGeneratorService() {
    StringGeneratorService mock = mock(StringGeneratorService.class);
    // adding the missing mocked method behavior here
    when(mock.generateRandomAlphaNumericString()).thenReturn("expectedMockedValue");
    return mock;
}
```

Comment: I have edittet my stringGeneratorService but still name returns null. Do you have any idea?

Answer (score 0):

As I see this is a unit test for your Rest Controller class.

I would suggest naming the Test Class as below as a good practice

Class Name:***StudentServer***.class

Junit Class Name: ***StudentServerTest***.class

Now Coming to your real issue.

1] I see you have autowired your dependency class (***StudentService***.class). Instead you need to mock it as

```
@MockBean
private StudentService studentService;
```

2] You do not need ***StringGeneratorService*** bean/object in your test class because, its method is not directly called from your controller class.

Its method is instead called from your service class and since, you mock your service class itself, this class is not visible in your controller class at all.

Remove this

```
@Autowired
public StringGeneratorService stringGeneratorService;
```

3] Now define the mock behavior as below and then assert

```
@Test
public void testGenerateStudent() throws Exception {

   Student student = new Student();
   student.setName("TestStudent");
   Mockito.when(studentService.getRandomStudent()).thenReturn(student);

   mockMvc.perform(MockMvcRequestBuilders.get("/generate-student"))
         .andExpect(MockMvcResultMatchers.status().isOk())
         .andDo(print())
         .andExpect(MockMvcResultMatchers.jsonPath("$.name").isNotEmpty());

   }
```